# iOS: return from pushed ViewController via delegate methods?

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, modalviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I've been wrestling with this for almost 2 hours now and no luck.

I have a View Controller. Lets call it First. I press a button and it takes me to Second view controller using a modal style. In Second I add some data which I can save or discard via two navigation bar buttons: Save and Cancel. both do what they do and then they return me to the previous screen. I implemented a protocol and I use the delegate. So far everything works fine.

Today I decided to have a Third View Controller which can be accessed from the Second VC. The problem is I couldn't move to THIRD until I changed the transition from First to Second to PUSH (instead of modal). Now I can go from First to Second and from Second to Third. All good again.

THE PROBLEM : If I press Cancel or Save on the Second VC, it calls the methods, it uses the delegate to go to FIRST and execute some function but when it calls:

`[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

nothing happens and Im stuck on the Second view. Basically I was using MODAL with Delegate and protocol methods... I switched to PUSH, and I cant get rid of my Second view and return to First. It seems like the dismissViewController doesnt do anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I can fix all this by removing the cancel button and using the BACK which comes by default with PUSH but I just want to know what the problem is with it.. THANK YOU !!

Comment: Use popViewController:animated when pushing viewControllers onto the navigation stack. dismissViewController:animated is strictly for modalViews.

Comment: Thanks @HubertKunnemeyer ! Thats the right solution and it works !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your 2nd viewContrller call the `UINavigationController`'s method `popViewControllerAnimated:` or `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`. This will pop the controller (the one calling, which is the 2nd) off the nav stack. You can get the navigation controller in a `UIViewController` via its property `navigationController`.

Comment: Worked perfectly ! Thank you so much ! But just for the record. Why exactly wasnt the other method working ?

Comment: Nvm Hubert explained it above. Dismiss is only for modal Views!